# How do you remove flash from Galaxy Tab 10.1?

Tags: adobe-flash

The browser is slow and maybe it's flash but I cant figure out how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try using browsers like `Dolphin Browser` or `Opera` which have an option called Flash on Demand, wherein flash objects are loaded only if you want them to.

Comment: I haven't used the Galaxy Tab, but I know the default browser on some devices does have an option for loading plugins on demand. Make sure to poke around though all the settings and see if you already may have this option.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about Dolphin but that doesn't help with my actual problem of removing flash. I just want it gone. I don't need it on the tablet and I don't to wonder if it's messing with the browser. And I REALLY want to stop it from nagging me to update it every day.

Comment: I don't really think flash can be completely removed. Majority of the sites use flash, and hence you'll need to load them. When your device does not find flash, it'll definitely ask you to update. That's why I use Dolphin, where flash content of the website is not loaded, resulting in faster page loads.